# Best approach for automatically generating I18N key strings in Java

Tags: java, internationalization, key, auto-generate

I've taken a look at the following post to grasp a basic idea of how to deal with I18N:
[Where to place i18n key strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992977/where-to-place-i18n-key-strings-in-java)

 But more than that, I have an intention of automatically generating a Java class with constants storing key strings of I18n property files. I know it could be feasibly done using Java itself, however, I wonder which is the best approach (using Ant, Batch or something else...)?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to give the identifiers yourself.
The ID can give hint to the translator what the string is about.

In fact, some consistency in naming convention is best:
 dialog.print.title = Print
 menu.file.print = Print

The two entries have to be translated differently in some languages (for instance in French it would be "Imprimer" for a button and "Impression" for a label / title).

Think it it this way: would you like to maintain some code where all variable names are machine generated?